# On the existence of exhausting sequences for thin sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding the proof of the existence of exhausting sequences for thin sets in [Cohen and Elliott (2015)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781493928668), and would appreciate it if someone could help shed some light on the situation, or if anyone could furnish (a reference to) an alternative proof.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \{\mathcal F_t\},P)$ be a filtered probability space satisfying the usual conditions. Denote the optional $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty[ \times \Omega$ by $\Sigma$. The **graph** of a stopping time $T$ is $$ [T] = \{ (t,\omega) \in [0,\infty[\times\Omega : T(\omega)=t < \infty \}. $$

A set $A \in \Sigma$ is called **thin** if there exists a sequence of stopping times $\{ S_n \}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $A \subseteq \cup_{n\in\mathbb N}[S_n]$. Moreover, if $[S_n]\cap[S_m]=\emptyset$ whenever $n\neq m$, then $\{ S_n \}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is called an **exhausting sequence** for $A$.

My question is regarding the existence of exhausting sequences for thin sets. Cohen and Elliott state the following theorem.

> **Theorem.** Any thin set admits an exhausting sequence.

I don't see how their proof establishes the existence of such a sequence, unfortunately. Here is their proof.

> **Proof.** Suppose $A \subseteq \cup_{n\in\mathbb N}[S_n]$. Write $T_n$ for the stopping time whose graph is given by $$ \left(A \setminus \bigcup_{k<n}[S_k]\right) \bigcap [S_n]. \label{1}\tag{1}$$
>   Then the $T_n$ have disjoint graphs and $A = \cup_n [T_n]$.

It is easy to see that the $T_n$ have disjoint graphs and that $A = \cup_n [T_n]$. However, I do have the following question.

> **Question.** How does one know that there exists a stopping time with a graph given by \eqref{1}?

Since \eqref{1} lies inside $[S_n]$, it seems natural to try to modify $S_n$ so that its graph is indeed given by \eqref{1}, yet I don't see a way of doing this.

One thought I had was to call the set in \eqref{1} $B_n$, and to consider the restriction of the stopping time $S_n$ to the set $\pi_\Omega(B_n)$. ($\pi_\Omega$ is the projection operator.) For this to work (that is, for the restriction to be a stopping time), I need $\pi_\Omega(B_n)$ to be $\mathcal F_{S_n}$-measurable, which I believe is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your notation and change a little of your description.
Let $L=\{\omega: 1_{B_n}(S_n(\omega),\omega)=1 \} $.
Since $B_n\in\Sigma$ and $S_n$ is a stopping time, then $ L\in \mathscr{F}_{S_n}$ and the restriction $T_n=(S_n)_L $ is a stopping time with a graph given by (1).

Comment: If I'm reading your answer correctly, then $L = \pi_\Omega(B_n)$. How do you know this projection is appropriately measurable? One might appeal to the measurable projection theorem, but then one would need, at the minimum, that $B_n \in \mathcal B \otimes \mathcal F_{S_n}$. Which I suppose is true, but I don't see how to show it.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Please use following result: If $X$ is a optional process(in fact, progressive measurable is sufficient) and $T$ is a stopping time, then $X(T)\in\mathscr{F}_T$.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was overthinking how to construct the appropriate stopping time. My problem is resolved by the following construction.

Let $T$ be a stopping time, and consider any $\Sigma$-measurable $A \subseteq [T]$. We construct a stopping time $S$ such that $[S]=A$ by setting $S(\omega) = t$ whenever $(t,\omega) \in A$. On the other hand, when $(t,\omega) \notin A$ for all $t\in[0,\infty[$, set $S(\omega) = \infty$.

It is straightforward to verify that $S$ is a well-defined map from $\Omega$ to $[0,\infty]$, and that $[S]=A$. The fact that $S$ is a stopping time then follows from the [measurable projection theorem](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2016/11/08/measurable-projection-and-the-debut-theorem/) and this lemma in Cohen and Elliott.

> **[Lemma 7.3.6.](https://books.google.com/books?id=qWb_CgAAQBAJ&q=lemma%207.3.6#v=snippet&q=lemma%207.3.6&f=false)** Suppose $T$ is a random time with values in $[0,\infty]$. Then, $T$ is a stopping time if and only if $[T]\in \Sigma$.

Thus, we only need to check that $S$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable. Note that for any $t \in [0,\infty[$, \begin{align} 
\{S \le t \} &= \{ \omega:S(\omega) \le t \} \\
&= \pi_\Omega (A \cap [0,t]\times\Omega).
\end{align}

Since $A$ is $\mathcal B \otimes \mathcal F$-measurable, the measurable projection theorem guarantees that $S$ is a random time.